# Laravel API: How to make a default image in a table instead of NULL

Tags: laravel

I am currently working on having a default image in a table instead of null. I already have an API that will put an image in that specific column (web_banner_profile) which is a POST method and a DELETE method that will make that column NULL, all of which using postman. I want to know how I can put a default image on all of the webinars table in the web_banner_profile.

This is the Banner Upload Controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Banner;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
// use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class BannerUploadController extends Controller
{
    public function FileUpload(Request $request, $id)
    {
        
        $uploaded_files = $request->file->store('public/uploads/');
        
        $webinar = Banner::find($id);
        $webinar->web_banner_profile = $request->file->hashName();

        $results = $webinar->save();
        if($results){
            return ["result"=>"Image Added"];
        }else{
            return ["result"=>"Image Not Added"];
        }

        return ["result"=>"$uploaded_files"];

    }

    public function DeleteBanner($id)
    {
    
        $webinar = Banner::find($id);
        if(is_null($webinar)){
            return response()->json('Record not found!', 401);
        }
        $webinar->update(['web_banner_profile' => null]);

        return response('Banner Deleted', 200);

    }

    }
```

This is the webinar table migration:

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateWebinarTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('webinar', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('web_title');
            $table->text('web_description');
            $table->dateTime('web_start_date_time')->nullable();   
            $table->dateTime('web_end_date_time')->nullable();   
            $table->string('status')->nullable();
            $table->string('remarks')->nullable();
            $table->string('web_banner_profile')->nullable();            
            $table->bigInteger('created_by')->unsigned()->nullable(); 
            $table->bigInteger('updated_by')->unsigned()->nullable(); 
            $table->string('web_link')->nullable();
        
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('webinar', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('admins');
            $table->foreign('updated_by')->references('id')->on('admins');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('webinar');
    }
}
```

Any type of help/suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Personally I would just leave that field empty and decide which image to show in the view/when displaying the image. If the field is null, show your web_banner, else the image stored in the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider using one of the [Eloquent model events](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events), specifically the `created` event. Something like the following:

```php
class Webinar extends Model
{
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::created(function ($webinar) {
            $webinar->update(['web_banner_profile' => 'your-image.jpg']);
        });
    }
}
```

Then whenever a new `Webinar` is created, the `created` event will be triggered and your default `web_banner_profile` value will be added to that record.

You don't have to hard code the value `your-image.jpg`, you could obtain it from a `config` of `env` file if you didn't want it in your code base to (arguably) make changing the value easier.

Comment: I will try this yes thank you. But where will I put the image in the folder of my project?

Comment: @Mhoreen The simplest way would be to use the [Laravel filesystem](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem) and have your default image in the `storage` folder of your app.

Comment: Is this an appropriate and correct way to put the directory? 
**C:\xampp\htdocs\drv-api\storage\app\public\default.png**

Comment: or **storage\app\public\default.png**

Comment: If you are asking what value to save in the database, just store the image name, do not store an absolute path (so just store `default.png`). Storing the file in `storage/app/public` is acceptable.

Comment: Good day @Peppermintology! I would like to consult you with something regarding a Laravel API. Where can I contact you? Thank you.